# Meaning of tensor expression

Tags: tensors

If  $\epsilon$  is an alternating unit tensor and $\mu$ is any arbitrary tensor, then what does the

expression $\epsilon : \mu = 0$  mean ? 
I came across this is some textbook I was reading. Is is tensor product or something else ?

Comment: For matrices this usually means componentwise multiplication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand a bit on my comment:

Two dots in the context of tensors may denote the simultaneous contraction of two indices. Just as with matrices, if $R$ and $S$ are a $(2,0)$ and a $(0,2)$ tensor respectively, then $R:S$ is the scalar $R^{ij} S_{ij}$ (sum over repeated indices).